# Align the text on the right side of an image having float left in a container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to create a "card" for an element, it will have an image, a title, a sub-title and a description, what I want is that the card should be aligned to the left (attached to the left border) but when I float the text to the right I get this behavior.. And the position of the card depends on the max width I set the text. How can I fix this?

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwet7t80/) to show the whole code:

This is the code I used to create the cards

```
<div class="first__section">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="schede__container">
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                    <h1>test</h1>

                    <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want exactly the fiddle looks good for me.

Comment: It's because of the width of the window, try to resize the window where you view the result, you'll see that the card get's aligned to the middle and I want it to stay attached to the left border

Comment: @LorenzoSignorin I have posted a working solution work you. Just view it as it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Html:

```
<div class="first__section">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="schede__container">
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
               <div class="div-img">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                   </div>
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
                <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
                <div class="scheda__content">
                     <h1>test</h1>

                     <h2>test</h2>

                    <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.schede__container {
    border-left:1px solid #343333;
}
.scheda__realizzazione {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:40px 0 40px 20px;
    padding:40px 0 40px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #343333;
}
.div-img {
    float: left;
}
.scheda__content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 313px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.scheda__content h1 {
    color:#5C5A5B;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
}
.scheda__content h2 {
    color:#5C5A5B;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
.scheda__content p {
    color:#5C5A5B;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.first__section {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
}
.inner {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/256oxh52/

Comment: try to resize the window where you view the result, you'll see that the card get's aligned to the middle and I want it to stay attached to the left border

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some properties in the following CSS classes to achieve your target.

First of all put the image in separate div and content in separate div.

```
<div class="scheda__realizzazione">
    <div class="div-img">
        <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="scheda__content">
        <h1>test</h1>

        <h2>test</h2>

        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add width to your `.div_img` class that your images needs.

```
.div-img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Secondly you only need to set the `margin-left` in the `.scheda__content` class and remove all other styles in it. `margin-left : 150px;` will do the trick for you but I set it to `margin-left: 160px;` for some clarity.

```
.scheda__content {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

---

**[Working JSFiddle Demo Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/7yL5g5x7/)**

---

```css
.schede__container {
  border-left: 1px solid #343333;
}
.scheda__realizzazione {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 0 40px 20px;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343333;
}
.div-img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
.scheda__content {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
.scheda__content h1 {
  color: #5C5A5B;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.scheda__content h2 {
  color: #5C5A5B;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.scheda__content p {
  color: #5C5A5B;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.first__section {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
.inner {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="first__section">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="schede__container">
      <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div><div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div><div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div><div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div><div class="scheda__realizzazione">
        <div class="div-img">
          <img class="scheda__img" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scheda__content">
          <h1>test</h1>

          <h2>test</h2>

          <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. MAECENAS SUSCIPIT LIBERO ARCU, EU LAOREET ORCI TINCIDUNT NEC. MORBI NEC JUSTO VEL NULLA SOLLICITUDIN ACCUMSAN VITAE QUIS ENIM.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```